# Linux UDP client, how?

Tags: c, linux, udp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main () {
    char buf[4] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
    struct addrinfo adr, *res;
    adr.ai_family = AF_INET;
    adr.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    getaddrinfo ("192.168.1.1", NULL, &adr, &res);
    int sd = socket (res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sendto (sd, buf, sizeof (buf), MSG_OOB, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0)
          perror ("ERROR sendto"); //I have added an if tag and an error message posiblility
    return 0;
}
```

ERROE sendto: Operation not supported

This is the all of message. The beej's guide network programming, i have read the getaddrinfo second parameter is NULL, and i had compiling it, it will be good, there was no problem this line. At now time the problem is Operation not supported error message.

Comment: where do you specify the target port?

Comment: You should probably look at the return values of things like `sendto` and check `errno` appropriately.

Comment: Check this http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html

Comment: `getaddrinfo ("192.168.1.1", NULL, &adr, &res);` - you are specifying `NULL` as the service name... how you do expect that to resolve to a valid port number?

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be several mistakes.

First, I believe MSG_OOB is illegal for UDP. This is probably what the error message is trying to say. Try 0 instead.

Then, the `getaddrinfo()` call looks weird (at least I don't understand the point). You say "i had compiling it, it will be good, there was no problem this line" but then you don't have the error handling to prove it...

My hunch is that the address or port of the socket address you use in `sendto()` are incorrect and you will still get errors after fixing MSG_OOB. Is there a reason you aren't just setting them manually like [here](http://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-c-linux/) — Are you trying to make `getaddrinfo()` pick a suitable port for you? I don't think that works:

> If service is NULL, then the port number of the returned socket
>   addresses will be left uninitialized.